# After successfully Google login App is crashing in IOS(Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I am using Xcode 8.0, testing on iOS 10.0 and using manually installed the SDK,  GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h.

After successfully login App is crashing.Error message I mentioned below

Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[pinakinAudioListViewController signIn:didSignInForUser:withError:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc44e863c00'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010229034b **exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010596121e objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00000001022fff34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   132   3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102215a2e
>   ___forwarding_** + 526    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102215798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   Pinakin
>   0x0000000100e517af **37-[GIDSignIn
>   addCallDelegateCallback:]_block_invoke + 116  6   Pinakin
>
>   0x0000000100e49981 -[GIDCallbackQueue fire] + 147     7   Pinakin
>
>   0x0000000100e5735b -[GIDTokenFetchDelegate
>   didFinishTokenFetchWithAuth:fetcher:error:] + 53  8   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010221705c __invoking_** + 140    9   CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000102216ee1 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 289   10  Pinakin
>   0x0000000100e5c771 +[GTMOAuth2Authentication
>   invokeDelegate:selector:object:object:object:] + 207  11  Pinakin
>   0x0000000100e5ba79 -[GTMOAuth2Authentication
>   tokenFetcher:finishedWithData:error:] + 648   12  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010221705c **invoking_** + 140    13  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000102216ee1 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 289   14  Pinakin
>   0x0000000100e61bd3 **67-[GTMSessionFetcher
>   completionHandlerWithTarget:didFinishSelector:]_block_invoke + 268    15
>   Pinakin                             0x0000000100e692c5
>   __71-[GTMSessionFetcher invokeFetchCallbacksOnCallbackQueueWithData:error:]_block_invoke + 25
>     16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001064ff980
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12     17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001065290cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8     18  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x0000000106509a1d _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 733    19 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001022544f9
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102219f8d __CFRunLoopRun
>   + 2205    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102219494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420   22  GraphicsServices
>   0x00000001081c2a6f GSEventRunModal + 161  23  UIKit
>   0x0000000103449f34 UIApplicationMain + 159    24  Pinakin
>   0x0000000100daa00f main + 111     25  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010657568d start + 1  26  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

And I created custom login using this code

```
GIDSignIn *sigNIn=[GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
[sigNIn setDelegate:self];
[sigNIn setUiDelegate:self];
sigNIn.shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES;

sigNIn.scopes = @[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"];
sigNIn.clientID =@"851647387203-6n9vm1jpn8uv2c0g1qsrdi4nn69f8rh5.apps.googleusercontent.com";
[sigNIn signIn];
```

In AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {         

    BOOL wasHandled=false;
    if ([url.scheme hasPrefix:@"fb"]) {

        wasHandled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                    openURL:url
                                                          sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                                 annotation:annotation
                      ];

        //Facebook callback
    }
    else       //Google Plus callback
    {
        wasHandled= [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                                        sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                               annotation:annotation];

    }

    NSLog ( @"application openURL");
    NSLog ( @"URL = %@", url);
    NSLog ( @"Application = %@", sourceApplication);

    return wasHandled;
}
```

Comment: check once in `pinakinAudioListViewController` the delegate method `signIn:didSignInForUser:withError` method `pinakinAudioListViewController signIn:didSignInForUser:withError:` called or not

Comment: see this https://vinaymahipal.wordpress.com/tag/ios/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply implement the `signIn:didSignInForUser:withError:` method of delegate `GIDSignInDelegate` in your `pinakinAudioListViewController`.

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {
  NSLog(@"User signed in!");
}
```

Please do not forget to implement the `signIn:didDisconnectWithUser:withError:` as well.

Also see: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/protocol_g_i_d_sign_in_delegate-p

Answer (score 0):

Implement GIDSignInDelegate methods to your ViewController:

```
- (void)signInWillDispatch:(GIDSignIn *)signIn error:(NSError *)error
{
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn dismissViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@",user);
}
```

Also you can write this method to your AppDelegate class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation])  || ([[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation]);
}
```

Hope this was help you.